# Is there an issue with saving many shared preferences in an activity? (Kotlin/Java)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, hashmap, sharedpreferences

The user is able to save infinite key value pairs, but normal people would only save a few, and delete them.

I have seen other ways to save HashMap keys and values but decided to go with this because it seems simple, still open to suggestions.

```
val saveHashMapSP = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
            with(saveHashMapSP.edit()) {
                putString("HashMap $orderNumber", orderAndNoteMap[key])
                commit()
            }
```

(both key and value are strings)

Comment: It is OK to save infinite number of values . but shared-preferences main purpose is to save stuff like settings and user login and in your case it's seems a lot of data you need to save, so it's make more sense to use database instead. there is many option to use ORMs like ActiveAndroid ,Room and etc... if you put time to it ORMs are very simple to use